# TypeError: Cannot read property '$cookies' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to save a response from server to cookies, and here is how I'm trying to do

```
this.$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: SOME_URL,
            data: SOME_DATA,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': this.basicAuthorization
            }


        }).success(function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            this.$cookies.putObject('userData', data);
        }).error(function(data){

        });
    }
```

I also provided:

```
    angular.module('mymodule', [
            ....,
            'ngCookies'
        ])
    // ........
    LoginHandler.$inject = ['$http', '$cookies'];
    // ........
    constructor($http, $cookies){ ... }
```

What is causing the error? I'm using angularjs 1.4.0

**UPDATE**

I have already found out that `this` is not working as expected in .success() etc.
So I had to store this in some other variable.

Comment: `this.$cookies = $cookies` in contructor

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
var self = this;
this.$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: SOME_URL,
            data: SOME_DATA,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': this.basicAuthorization
            }

        }).success(function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            self.$cookies.putObject('userData', data);
        }).error(function(data){

        });
    }
```